# jQuery - Hide div when a textbox doesn't have focus, with exceptions

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code,

```
<div id="search-controls" style="display: none;">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <select>
         <option value="All">All sectors</option>
         <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
         <option value="Hr">Human Resources</option>
         <option value="Procurement">Procurement &amp; Supply Chain</option>
         <option value="Sales">Sales &amp; Marketing</option>
      </select>
      <select>
         <option value="All">Salary range</option>
         <option value="10000">£10,000 - £19,999</option>
         <option value="20000">£20,000 - £29,999</option>
         <option value="30000">£30,000 - £49,999</option>
         <option value="50000">£50,000 - £69,999</option>
         <option value="70000">£70,000 - £99,999</option>
         <option value="100000">£100,000+</option>
         <option value=""></option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <select>
         <option value="All">All job types</option>
         <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
         <option value="Temporary">Temporary</option>
         <option value="Interim">Interim</option>
      </select>
      <select>
         <option value="All">All job locations</option>
         <option value="Leicester">Leicester</option>
         <option value="Nottingham">Nottingham</option>
         <option value="Derby">Derby</option>
         <option value="Lincoln">Lincoln</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>

<input id="search-jobs" type="text" placeholder="Search">

<input class="icon-search" type="submit" value="">
```

jQuery

```
jQuery("#search-jobs").focus(function() {
    jQuery('#search-controls').slideDown(300);
}).blur(function() {
    jQuery('#search-controls').slideUp(300);
});
```

When you click on the search-jobs textbox it display the search controls (the 4 select options). At the moment when you go to pick a select option, the search controls disappear because the searchbox has lost focus. Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: What is your expected behaviour then? You just explain what you don't want but not what you want. Do you want once input has been focused, the DIV to be displayed persistently or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On blur, you can check to see what object has focus, and if it's your select options, you can not do the slide.

I have something similar in some code I was working on recently, in my case I wanted to prevent focus from being lost if the entry was invalid (e.g. "these two collections must total the same value").  I would force the focus back to the invalid field unless the other field was the one focused.

```
.blur(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(!$('#search-controls>.col-md-6>select').is(':focus')) {
        jQuery('#search-controls').slideUp(300);
    }
  },0);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8r56vbrf/)

Alternatively

```
.blur(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    if($('#search-controls>.col-md-6>select:focus').length == 0) {
        jQuery('#search-controls').slideUp(300);
    }
  },0);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dytpqe6o/)

**Edit:**

Added fiddles for each method.  I missed a container div that needed to be added to the selector to function correctly as well as the `setTimeout` delay necessary for the event to process in the correct order.

Asker may wish to make this blur a non-anonymous function so that he can add it to all of the dropdown's blur event as well, so that the user has a intuitive way to hide them again.

Comment: Thanks this works, but == 0 needed to be != 0 in my case.

Comment: It won't work, you need to use [event.relatedTarget](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#widl-FocusEvent-relatedTarget). Now this is accepted answer, i must be missing something...  Can you provide a MCVE?

Comment: Whoops, I'll fix that.  Lost track of my booleans while typing. :)

Comment: Ok how this can be accepted answer and get 5 upvotes? What i'm missing here?! As i understand your answer, it is: `jQuery("#search-jobs").focus(function() {
    jQuery('#search-controls').slideDown(300);
}).blur(function() {
    if(!$('#search-controls>select').is(':focus')) {
        jQuery('#search-controls').slideUp(300);
    }
});`  Correct?  But this absolutely doesn't work, so. FYI, `blur` handler is fired before `document.activeElement` is set... Now using `event.relatedTarget` https://jsfiddle.net/h6adk4ge/  But still, is it what exactly OP is looking for?

Comment: Can you make working fiddle for this? I think it did not worked as expected when i tried this.

Comment: This is working for me, I can post a fiddle if you like?

Comment: @A.Wolff i tried what you have commented and it hides on focus dropdown. it did not let me select any options and slide up.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi You surely tested it on FF, right? I should have mentioned it, doesn't work on FF. The workaround is to delaying a little the blur handler

Comment: @nsilva Ya, please  so i could remove my downvote and make it an upvote

Comment: Fiddle added, it will now function as advertised.

Comment: @Draco18s I find it funny in some way....  Something is really wrong here... But who cares!

Comment: @A.Wolff Fiddles are up, I would have @ tagged everyone, but there's a limit of 1 per comment.  You may peruse and update your vote as necessary.

Comment: @nsilva You may be interested in the edit I made.  I was working from memory and forgot a couple things. :)

Comment: @A.Wolff How often do you write code that functions perfectly the first time? ;)

Comment: I've added the updated code, thanks for this. It is safe to add right? ;)

Comment: @nsilva What do you mean "safe"?

Comment: Thanks all to appreciate my point. And make it correct for FF also.

Comment: @Draco18s Ya you are right but let me find it really suspect than a wrong answer can be so quickly upvoted and getting accepted...

Comment: @A.Wolff its like all moves towards one wolf . One downvote then all of them started down voting/upvoting

Comment: @ParthTrivedi It works in the copy of Firefox I have on my machine.  v42, what version are you running? (sidenote: I really dislike Firefox's current versioning system...)

Comment: @Draco18s it works for me i mentioned and thanks to make work with FF also.

Comment: @Draco18s Please accept all my apologies if i was wrong ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff No hard feelings, dude.  Reputation is just a number and your comment made me go pull up the code I'd *actually* written and test it with the asker's HTML.  It pointed out two errors I'd made.

Comment: For this type of search (where extra options show on focus), you would expect the search options to stay visible if you have a select option set and you click elsewhere on the page right?

Comment: @nsilva TBH that's a UI question.  I'd go ask that on [User Experience SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @nsilva IMO depending on what I'm doing, the dropdowns might be something I select once and then ignore, so yeah I wouldn't mind them hiding.  If they're options I'm going to want to fiddle with a lot, then having them hide would be annoying.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I am unsure what you mean.  Do you mean that the div hides when it should not?  Does increasing the time delay help?

Comment: @Draco18s - I've just come across one problem with this, if you have an option selected then you set focus to the search box again, you get a slide down and slide back up animation

Comment: @nsilva I cannot get that behavior in my Fiddle, do you?

Comment: @Draco18s - your fiddle is fine, same code on the site itself has this problem though; http://46.101.2.132/

Comment: @nsilva That's because your old code is still in the page http://s22.postimg.org/uugbqum41/dup.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slideToggle`

```js
jQuery("#search-jobs").click(function() {
    jQuery('#search-controls').slideToggle(300);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-controls" style="display: none;">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <select>
         <option value="All">All sectors</option>
         <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
         <option value="Hr">Human Resources</option>
         <option value="Procurement">Procurement &amp; Supply Chain</option>
         <option value="Sales">Sales &amp; Marketing</option>
      </select>
      <select>
         <option value="All">Salary range</option>
         <option value="10000">£10,000 - £19,999</option>
         <option value="20000">£20,000 - £29,999</option>
         <option value="30000">£30,000 - £49,999</option>
         <option value="50000">£50,000 - £69,999</option>
         <option value="70000">£70,000 - £99,999</option>
         <option value="100000">£100,000+</option>
         <option value=""></option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <select>
         <option value="All">All job types</option>
         <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
         <option value="Temporary">Temporary</option>
         <option value="Interim">Interim</option>
      </select>
      <select>
         <option value="All">All job locations</option>
         <option value="Leicester">Leicester</option>
         <option value="Nottingham">Nottingham</option>
         <option value="Derby">Derby</option>
         <option value="Lincoln">Lincoln</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>

<input id="search-jobs" type="text" placeholder="Search">

<input class="icon-search" type="submit" value="">
```

Comment: its `. mistake` only after `})`. I have updated answer.

Comment: Downvote is likely because it isn't addressing the asker's problem, which is that when the toggled select dropdowns are visible, clicking on one causes the select dropdowns to hide again.

Comment: I would but the only problem is the options hide if you were to select an option and then go to search something again